# Try catch, Java eclipse not catching exception

Tags: java, exception

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter file name:");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    creatingfeatures(name, "part1");
}

public static void creatingfeatures(String filename, String type) {
    String outputFile = "../data/" + type + "/" + type + ".csv";
    System.out.println("This is the output file: " + outputFile);
    try {
        CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true), ',');
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
            csvOutput.write(i);
            csvOutput.endRecord();
        }
        csvOutput.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter another file name (wrong name given)");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Hello all, when I use an invalid file name (Ie when the file is not found), the message under the catch was not printed. Anybody knows why?

Comment: Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead of explicitly closing `csvOutput` (not the issue, however).

Comment: Please take more care when removing code. The extra `}` surely belongs to a block, which was omitted, so remove that, as well. And don't kill your JVM like that.

Comment: Scumbag code: "Enter another filename" <kills program>.

Comment: "When the file is not found" But you're writing it. So, it'd be created, right?

Comment: @Nana Pls accept/upvote my answer if it solves your purpose

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/FileWriter.java#FileWriter.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%2Cboolean%29) it is clear, it does not gives exception for the wrong file name supplied to FileWriter, it rather creates new file if it is not present. Also if it is not able to create a file at a desired location, then it throws `IOException`. Just check at the location, it should have created files there.

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean
>   indicating whether or not to append the data written.
>
> Parameters:
>       fileName String The system-dependent filename.
>       append boolean if true, then data will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning. Throws:
>       `IOException` if the **named file exists but is a directory** rather than a regular file, **does not exist but cannot be created**, or **cannot**
>   **be opened for any other reason**

Answer (score 0):

You are catching just IOExceptions

```
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Please enter another file name (wrong name given)");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

If you have other kind of exceptions you have to catch them also.
Use:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Other kind of exception");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

instead or in addition to catch any kind of exceptions

```
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Please enter another file name (wrong name given)");
    System.exit(0);
}catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Other kind of exception");
    System.exit(0);
}
```